Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio" when installing minio on ubuntu 22.04
Trying to install minio server on ubuntu 22.04 following the instruction from here.
wget https://dl.min.io/server/minio/release/linux-amd64/archive/minio_20240611031330.0.0_amd64.deb -O minio.deb
sudo dpkg -i minio.deb

then created a Environment Variable File at the path of /etc/default/minio.
MINIO_ROOT_USER=myminioadmin
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minio-secret-key-change-me

# MINIO_VOLUMES sets the storage volume or path to use for the MinIO server.
# /mnt/data already existed 
MINIO_VOLUMES="/mnt/data". 

# MINIO_OPTS sets any additional commandline options to pass to the MinIO server.
# For example, `--console-address :9001` sets the MinIO Console listen port
MINIO_OPTS="--console-address :9001"

after running sudo systemctl start minio.service, I got an error saying
× minio.service - MinIO
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/minio.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-06-13 07:29:35 CST; 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.min.io
    Process: 2408813 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ -z "${MINIO_VOLUMES}" ]; then echo "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio"; exit 1; fi (code=exi>
        CPU: 1ms

telling me

Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio"

but as I see in the /etc/default/minio config file, MINIO_VOLUMES is set "/mnt/data"
any ideas how to get over it?
